# global message (notif) call on vueJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Probably a hackneyed question, but I don't understand it yet.

I have a main component that is always loaded in the application.

let's call him

DefaultContainer.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
     .... Notification List
   </div>
</template>
```

I use library for calling notifications

npm vue-notification
and connect it in the current component

```
<script>

import VueNotifications from 'vue-notifications'    
export default {
data: () => {
  return { 
    messages: []
  }
},
methods: {
  onNotification(message) {        
    this.showInfoMsg({ message: message });
  }
},

notifications: {
  showSuccessMsg: {
    type: VueNotifications.types.success,
    title: 'success',
    message: 'That\'s the success!'
  },
  showInfoMsg: {
    type: VueNotifications.types.info,
    title: 'info',
    message: 'Here is some info for you'
  },
  showWarnMsg: {
    type: VueNotifications.types.warn,
    title: 'warn',
    message: 'That\'s the kind of warning'
  },
  showErrorMsg: {
    type: VueNotifications.types.error,
    title: 'error',
    message: 'That\'s the error'
  }
}
}
</script>
```

when i call the method

```
this.showInfoMsg({ message: message });
```

all work correct

But in order to use it in another component, for example, for a separate page, I have to specify this library each time and make calls

is it possible to somehow access the DefaultContainer
and call this message without announcing

```
import VueNotifications from 'vue-notifications'
```

and

```
notifications: {
    showSuccessMsg: {
    ....
    }
}
```

for example, the test page has opened

Test.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
     <button @click="onNotificationShow()"  >button</button>
   </div>
</template>

export default {
    data: () => {
        return { 
        ......
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onNotificationShow() {        
           this.showInfoMsg({ message: 'Show on Test.vue'});
           //this i have error becouse showInfoMsg undefined
           //I need to call showInfoMsg from DefaultContainer
        }
    }
}
```

DefaultContainer.vue regardless of the open pages is always present

by structure -> loading vue

1. main.js (static srcipt)
2. App.vue + router (static vue + srcipt)
3. DefaultContainer.vue (static vue - this is notificationBar)
4. pageVue (test.vue or test2.vue) (dynamic vue can changed - this is pages for users for data)

Can I call this method in vue?

Comment: How about if you make the button with all necessary methods, etc. a component & reuse the Component from everywhere?

Comment: He is already used everywhere, because DefaultContainer is static and is present on all pages.

Comment: yes but `DefaultContainer` is a different object. Inside `onNotificationShow()` method (Test.vue) `this` is refering to Test.vue (not  `DefaultContainer.vue`) and `showInfoMsg()` is not exists in Text.vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a component `MyVueNotification.vue` then use the component from anywhere:

```js
// MyVueNotificaton.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="onNotificationShow()"  >button</button>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueNotifications from 'vue-notifications'    

export default {
data: () => {
  return { 
messages: []
  }
},
methods: {
  onNotification(message) {        
this.showInfoMsg({ message: message });
  }
},

notifications: {
  showSuccessMsg: {
type: VueNotifications.types.success,
title: 'success',
message: 'That\'s the success!'
  },
  showInfoMsg: {
type: VueNotifications.types.info,
title: 'info',
message: 'Here is some info for you'
  },
  showWarnMsg: {
type: VueNotifications.types.warn,
title: 'warn',
message: 'That\'s the kind of warning'
  },
  showErrorMsg: {
type: VueNotifications.types.error,
title: 'error',
message: 'That\'s the error'
  }
}
}
</script>
```

Then from `Test.vue` use the `MyVueNotification.vue` component:

```js
// Test.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <my-vue-notificaton></my-vue-notification>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyVueNotification from ./MyVueNotification.vue

export default {
  components: {
    "my-vue-notification": MyVueNotification
  }
}

</script>
```